# Only scrolling inside one div, while website stays positioned

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm trying to create a website with the following.

On top there's just a basic horizontal menu. Below that, on the left side, is another subcategory. The content will be on the right of the subcategory and can be very long.

Now what I would like is that when you scroll anywhere on the page, it only scrolls the content div while everything else stays at its original position. I have been thinking about it for some hours now but I cannot really come up with a solution on how to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left_side"></div>
    <div class="right_side"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

.container {
width:1000px;
}

.left_side {
float:left;
width:250px;
height:500px;
background:green;   
}

.right_side {
float:right;
width:750px;
height:1500px;
background:yellow;
}
```

Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like this? http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=202/202.css

Comment: i think it is the use of position:fixed. Watch the HTML source (inspect element) of http://www.kantoorwinkel-online.nl/aboutus.html

Comment: You're right. If I give all the divs except for the content one a position:fixed they all stay and it works like it has to. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 5):

Answer was given by @jao's comment. Setting all divs, except for the content one, to `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 4):

Add the `overflow:auto` style to its class.

Full explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Will that by default scroll the content in that element even if you scroll elsewhere on the screen? the example in comments scrolls the content if using your mouse wheel on the non-scrolling areas too...

Comment: Moo-Juice's example doesn't work. I tried it and it also scrolls the whole website.